# USB-Ethernet not recognized by macbook, no Ethernet option under Network

Tags: network, usb, ethernet

I have a 16-inch Macbook Pro 2019 with Big Sur (11.4) and an Ethernet cable that I plug into an **UTP-USB** adapter ([TP-Link UE300](https://www.tp-link.com/nl/home-networking/computer-accessory/ue300/)) which then goes into a dongle that brings it to **USB-C**. Not the prettiest set-up, and it also doesn't work. [According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh11939/mac) I should just go to Network and pick Ethernet, but I don't have that option.

[image: No Ethernet]

Now what?
(I've checked and the Ethernet cable works)

USB tree structure

[image]

Comment: Try choosing thunderbolt bridge, it should show up.

Comment: Can you add make and model of your UTP-USB adapter?

Comment: I don't see any ethernet options under thunderbolt bridge. The adapter is a TP-Link (UE300). https://www.tp-link.com/nl/home-networking/computer-accessory/ue300/

Comment: Cay you hit the apple logo in the top left corner, then about this mac and system information. Then scroll to USB and post a screenshot of the tree structure there.

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve it?

Comment: Oh, this helped: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202617 TLDR: connect it while network is open

Comment: Then the order of operation is the key for this configuration to be possible.
I suggest you to make an answer from your success, because, it isn't that easy to get this secret from the Apple documentation :). They have a deep culture of a user experience as a travel in a haunted castle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular adapter doesn’t seem to be supported on macOS versions past Yosemite (10.10).  Per the tech specs listed on the page for the TP-Link UE300, it lists:

> Plug and Play in Windows (XP/Vista/7/8/8.1/10), Mac OS X (10.9/10.10), Linux OS. NB: stuurprogramma nodig voor Mac OS X (10.5-10.8).

<sup>The text “stuurprogramma nodig voor” is Dutch and translates to “driver needed for.”</sup>

This appears to only have built-in support up util Yosemite and an external driver is necessary for OS X versions Leopard through Mountain Lion (10.5 through 10.8).

That particular USB driver uses the Realtek RTL8111 chipset which seems to have been dropped from macOS versions past Yosemite as evidenced by this [Hackintosh blog post](http://lnx2mac.blogspot.com/p/realtekrtl81xx-osx-driver.html) where the author laments the condition of the existing drivers and the need to port the Linux driver to macOS.

Your best bet is to get a new, compatible adatper.

Comment: Ah, I asked that question 3 years ago, so it's no longer relevant but thanks for the answer anyway! ^^

Comment: No worries!  I like to close the loop on things and I saw that someone else had the same issue in comments so I thought I would research it and post a resolution.  Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to TP link website and install a driver that is compatible with your OS, buying Ethernet adapter directly from Apple allows you to plug and play instantly